# Cannot re-enable sound notifications for Skype on Windows 7 SP1

Tags: windows-7, audio, skype, notifications, mute

I've tried to reset everything related to sounds/notifications to default configuration. My Skype on Windows 7 seems to be muted since the last time I set it to be so - i.e. when it keeps popping up sound/balloon about new incoming messages, I mute it.

Now, how can I go back to where it was? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried **unmuting it from the Volume Control Mixer**?

In the system tray, click the volume icon, and a popup appears, like so:
[image]

Click `Mixer` and this appears:

[image]

Make sure that the highlighted controls are set to unmute.  Neither System Sounds or Skype should be muted.

Mixer has a list of all the programs that make sound in the computer, Skype will be on the list, but perhaps under a different sound device.  You should be able to click the volume icon in the system tray once (Windows 7) and **see a slider for each device**. so try clicking the mixer button under each device to **see if Skype is hidden in one of them**.

Or **perhaps a device has been disabled**. Try right-clicking on the Volume icon, select Playback devices, and see if any devices in the list that show up are disabled?

Comment: There's something wrong with my skype. I can't find skype in the mixer. About different devices, how can I reach the list?